# Sharing Gallery Between Multiple Wordpress Sites

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a solution that allows multiple websites to share the same table/database for just the gallery page.

The scenario is that one website will host all the images uploaded while the other website will pull images from that site and filter them to only have the ones relevant to itself. I only want to share the table/database for just the gallery images and not other posts.

Does anyone know if there is a solution that already exists for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared databases (it's called a remote database when accessing one not on your domain/server) are possible, but they tend to get pretty hairy very quickly.

You'd be better suited to use the WP REST API to query posts (if it's a custom post type (also note if it is a custom post type, you may need to register the endpoint on the API: [Read more here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/))) or if it's media library files, you can query media directly using http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/media/

This exact scenario is almost exactly what the v2 API was designed to deal with, and it will save you an enormous amount of stress instead of relying on two installations working on the same database.

Alternatively, you could host the images on a CDN and make queries to the CDN based on that particular site's needs.